# Does Sugru (Formerol) decay underwater?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, hydrolysis, carbon-family, organosilicon-compounds

[Sugru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugru) is described as waterproof and dishwasher-safe, but I still wonder if it will decay quickly (within months) if submerged in room-temperature tap water.

Aren't silicone rubbers susceptible to hydrolysis?

Comment: Mold can grow on silicone sealants (which is why they are sometimes mixed with mold suppressor) but they are otherwise a standard material for use in humid environments like kitchen sinks and bathrooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the [silicone monomer *does* hydrolyze in water, causing crosslinking](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/condensation-cure-silicone). However, the resultant crosslinked polymer is stable.

Second, silicone is, one might say, *rabidly* [hydrophobic](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12633-014-9188-0). For water to cause degradation, it would have to penetrate, but is confined to the surface. However, silicones *are* [highly permeable to water vapor](https://www.versaperm.com/materials/Silicone%20and%20vapour%20permeability.php). so degradation *might* occur, depending on the formulation and additives.

As for the specifics for the proprietary formulation for Sugru, you'd need to test if it meets a specific need. It's ~50-75% silanes, the remainder talc and other substances, so that would would change its water resistance.

Comment: *"the resultant crosslinked polymer is stable."* -- so would it just become harder (less elastic)?

Comment: It is the process by which Sugru changes from a plastic form to an elastic solid.